# BJT input impedance and current gain

Tags: transistors, bjt

I'm reading this article: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Dark-activated-light-circuit.php

And in there I see this schematic:

[image: 1]

I'm highly confused as to how this would even work. First of all, the article mentions that base-collector resistance is around 400K. Looking at the [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N3903-D.PDF), the only information I can find is max 10kOhm of input impedance. Is 400K some sort of insider info that I'm not privy to?

Second, in dark conditions, the current would prefer the base of the transistor instead of going through the photoresistor. 100kOhm means that 0.03 mA would flow through that resistor into the base. 2N3904 gain at 0.1 mA is about hFE = 40, so this would allow a maximum of 1.2 mA to flow from collector to emitter, am I wrong? At 0.03 mA, would it even be sufficient to saturate the transistor to switch the transistor on?

Comment: It'll be about 0.025 mA.

Comment: Where did you find that the gain is 40? I only found gain vs collector current, not gain vs base current. At a collector current of 1mA, the minimum gain is 70. In any event, 1mA is enough to make the LED glow, even if the transistor is not saturated. But if the gain is more than 40, the actual LED current will be higher proportionally (up to the saturation maximum).

Comment: \$V_{BE(sat)} \approx 0.7\$ so the base current will be about \$ {3-0.7 \over 100} = 23 \mu A\$.

Comment: @copper.hat, the LED will turn on even if the BJT is not in saturation. Just an observation.

Comment: You're right, I misread because I've been thinking about it as Ic = hFE * Ib, so I kind of thought gain would be based on how much current goes into the base. In this case then, how would I figure out how much current would saturate the base to switch the transistor on?

Comment: Well, the rule of thumb for saturated switches is that you want the base current to be around 1/10th or 1/20th of the collector current. But in reality, if Ib is Ic/hfe (for the min hfe) then that should be OK. As long as you make sure you are using the minimum hfe. If hfe is higher than the min, then the switch will increasingly go into saturation.

Comment: You also have to use realistic estimates for Vbe and Vce if you are going to cut it close. I guess that is why some people prefer to just use Ic/20 or Ic/10. That is enough overdrive to achieve saturation without doing many calculations. Again, the LED may glow somewhat even if the transistor is not saturated.

Comment: Perhaps saturating the transistor is not necessary to turn the LED on hard as it is already dark :-)

Comment: Then would it be correct to say that if I'm running 30mA through the LED, on the base pin I would want somewhere around 1.5-3mA? With 1V Vbe (worst case), a 1K resistor on the base would actually work fine?

Comment: Running \$30mA\$ through \$330 \Omega\$ will drop \$9.9V\$. Just wiring the above directly (meaning skipping the transistor) can drive about \$6mA\$ at most.

Comment: Ignore the 330ohm resistor. I will be using different values for resistor and LED. Just assume there's going to be 30mA going through the LED.

Comment: If you are operating in the linear region, then Figure 15 shows \$h_{FE} \approx 70\$, so you need to drive the base with \$\approx 0.5 mA\$. (But why? just saturate it.)

Comment: Yes, 1.5 to 3mA should saturate it if you are going for Ic=30mA. I don't think Vce will be 1V, though. More like 0.2 or 0.3V at saturation. Please note that quite a few LED's are rated at 20mA, and they are pretty bright with that current. Make sure your LED really can handle 30mA and make sure that is really what you want.